# Why python executable loses its icon after copying into another folder?

Tags: python, exe, ico

I created one file `.exe` with `auto-py-to-exe` and added `.ico` file. When the file was in output folder the `.ico` was working as intended and my custom icon was there but every time when I copy this file into another folder it changes back to default python icon. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Share your code so it's *reproducible* by others.

Comment: I don't think it's code related here(?) Whole 'add .ico file' thing happens purely in auto-py-to-exe config, there is 0 lines of code related to that in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this line, it will make your .exe in one file with icon you set and it will be windowed.

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --icon=myicon.ico --windowed app.py
```

Comment: ```--icon "C:/Users/cp24/Downloads/tools_icon.ico``` is what auto-py-to-exe is using and it works untill I change it's location on my PC.

Comment: I understand you, but try to do it with line I posted and tell me is it working. It is same thing but i never had problems with pyinstaller. One hint, be sure your icon is in the same folder as your script when using pyinstaller. And I asume you are using .exe version of auto-py-to-exe ?

Comment: I tried it and it looks like .ico works only in desired output folder and nowhere else.

Comment: After some blind shots it worked, still no idea why it's so messy